# Where can I find the information about a particular Android Studio update?

Tags: android-studio

In Android Studio when it shows a message saying that updates are available for Android SDK and Tools, all I see are two items:

- Android Support Repository revision 43.0.0
- Google Repository revision 43

Is there a more detailed list of what’s included in those updates? Are those incremental updates that would be added latter in a minor release?

The download size is 454 MB but this is the second time I see one of those in a much shorter period of time that I’m used to see updates available for Xcode, but then at least I can skip some updates in Xcode if I’m not particularly interested in the new features.